# Can jQuery nextUntil perform my function

Tags: jquery

I can do this

```
        $("#id")
            .closest("div")
            .nextUntil("div.stop-class")
            .addClass("new-class");
```

What I want to do is this

```
        $("#id")
            .closest("div")
            .nextUntil("div.stop-class")
            .myFunction(someParameter);
```

I can [extend jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/), but is there another way?

Comment: Sure. `myFunction($("#id").closest("div").nextUntil("div.stop-class"), someParameter)`. The real question is what you want `myFunction` to do...

Comment: If you *can* extend jQuery and it does what you want, why wouldn't you do that?

Comment: @Mike - thanks - that's what I was looking for.  Feel free to post as an answer and I'll vote for it.

Comment: @freedonmn-m, I'd avoid a complex solution in favour of a simpler one.

Answer (score 0):

The `.nextUntil` method just returns a jQuery object for chaining, the same as `.closest` or any other selector method, including `$("#id")` itself.

To add your own chaining method to jQuery, you don't need to use `$.fn.extend` and can just add a new function directly to `$.fn.`, and return `this` (or the further result of this.chain function, eg:

```
$.fn.myFunction = function(param) {
    return this.css( "color", param );  // or whatever is required
}

$("#id").myFunction();
```

or, with the nextUntil:

```
$("#id")
        .closest("div")
        .nextUntil("div.stop-class")
        .myFunction("green");
```